# ouput facebook url comments json_decode

Tags: php, facebook, json

I am trying to output the comments of a facebook page in PHP. For example:

http://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://www.example.com

Can someone please explain how to decode this correctly so I can have all comments appearing on a page?

I have tried a couple of different scripts/expamples but they all seem to be returning no results or an error, so i think maybe the graph API has changed since.

```
    //get the json string from URL
        $data = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com");

        //transform json to associative array
        $data = json_decode($data, true);

        //use only the comments array
        $comments = $data['http://www.example.com']['comments']['data'];

        foreach($comments as $comment) { 
            echo $comment['from']['name'];
            echo $comment['message'];
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//get the json string from URL
$data = file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://www.example.com");

//transform json to associative array
$data = json_decode($data, true);

//use only the comments array
$comments = $data['http://www.example.com']['comments']['data'];

//you should only see the comments array printed
echo "<pre>"; print_r($comments); echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Can you please update your code to show the ouput of all comments. I seem to be only able to output the first comment. Thanks

Comment: This will print all comments.

Comment: What is the best way to ouput the comments array to show all comments. When i did a foreach statement I seem to be only able to get the first comment.

Comment: Then it's something wrong with your code. Update your question with the code you use.

Comment: I've updated with my question. My code above outputs the name and comment of the first person only.

Comment: Sorry, what i mean is it shows the particular comment, but it doesn't show anyone elses reply to that comment. So i need to show both everyones comments and their replys.

Comment: The answer appears right - you may have some comments "hidden" because of security issues. Log off and see whihc comments are public and which are private; unless you autheticate your graph call, you're only going to get the public ones.